flutter: AD_ID is always missing and appears as a warning in Google Play Console
I am using google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0
I cannot get rid of the warning on Google Play Console that states
Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

I want to use ads, so I have ensured I have added.
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

To this file android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
I am now losing my mind over this, I have tried this too, to remove it just in case something else is adding it
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>

I have checked the .aab to ensure the permission is present, which is in AndroidManifest.xml.
Now I am at a complete loss as to what is required to make the warning disappear and ensure that the AD ID can be used by Google Admob in my Flutter app.
The only thing left is that the warning states one of your active artifacts - so is the issue within a dependency which is using the AD ID, but is not requesting the permission?
How do I check for that?
How can I force the affected manifest to request the AD ID permission?
Deps
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  uuid: ^4.4.0
  english_words: ^4.0.0
  provider: ^6.0.0
  validators: ^3.0.0
  fl_chart: ^0.68.0
  card_swiper: ^3.0.1
  intl: ^0.19.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.11
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  hive_generator: ^2.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.1.3
  prompt_dialog: ^1.0.16
  animated_snack_bar: ^0.4.0
  confirm_dialog: ^1.0.3
  flutter_isolate: ^2.0.4
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0
  fluttericon: ^2.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  alert_dialog: ^1.0.2
  bulleted_list: ^0.0.1+0.1a
  in_app_purchase: ^3.2.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  cross_file: ^0.3.4+1
  dio: ^5.5.0+1
  cryptography: ^2.7.0
  cryptography_flutter: ^2.3.2
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  video_player: ^2.9.1
  file_picker: ^8.0.0+1
  screenshot: ^3.0.0
  share_plus: ^10.0.2
  flutter_sharing_intent: ^1.1.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0
  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.6


What other dependencies do you have in pubspec.yaml?

@tomerpacific - many! I have edited my question.

I would go over the relevant dependencies that might need to include the permission and see if they do.

It only started after using google_mobile_ads. So it is 100% that. Google got back to me and basically said its fine :-/
